# Как показать что функция отсуствует потому что не имеет смысла, а не что ее забыли?

Tags: c++

В проекте есть семейство шаблонных функций которые принимают аргументы с некоторым ожидаемым интерфейсом. Примерно так:

```
template<typename T>
void do_some(...)
{
   //...
   const auto c = T::some();
   //...
}

template<typename T>
void do_other(...)
{
   //...
   const auto o = T::other();
   //...
}
```

Так вот, требуется для некоторых специализаций запретить вызов `T::other()` и выводить ошибку компиляции в этом месте.

Первое решение это просто не делать объявление `other` для нужной специализации `T`, но тогда компилятор будет выводить ошибку об отсутствии `other` и не понятно что делать. Хотелось бы выводить нечто вразумительное чтобы было понятно, что вызов `other` для данного `T` запрещен, а не что его забыли.

Второе решение - использовать `static_assert`, вот так:

```
int Spec::other()
{
    static_assert(false, "you must not call `other` func");
}
```

Но тогда ошибка выводится всегда когда компилятор встречает определение `Spec::other`, а не в месте ее вызова в `do_other`. Как выводить ошибку когда требуется?

Comment: `template<>
void do_other<Spec>(...) = delete;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Объявить "неправильные" специализации `other` как `= delete` явным образом. Явное `= delete` - это как раз способ выразить то, что специализацию не "забыли", а умышленно запретили.

Comment: Вы имете в виду `int Spec::other() = delete`?

Comment: @Cerbo: Да, но именно и только для тех специализаций, которые вы считаете недопустимыми.

Answer (score 2):

Есть еще хитрость, если все ж таки нужно выводить осмысленное сообщение об ошибке. Заключается она в том чтобы сделать `Spec::other` шаблоном, вот так например:

```
template<typename _dummy = int>
int Spec::other()
{
    static_assert(false, "Do not call `Spec::other` func");
    return -1;
}
```

В таком случае `static_assert` будет срабатывать при инстанцировании `Spec::other`, то есть в месте ее вызова. Даже несмотря на то, что параметр шаблона имеет значение по-умолчанию.

Comment: Этот вариант будет допустимым только в том случае, если данный шаблон допускает хоть одну корректную специализацию.

Comment: @AnT Под этот, вы имеете в виду `Spec::other`? И допустим в каком смысле? У меня на VC2017 в таком виде работет и ничего дополнительно не требуется.

Comment: C++ формально запрещает писать шаблоны, для которых невозможна ни одна корректная специализация. Разумеется, компилятор не может в общем случае распознать нарушение этого требования, поэтому для него "no diagnostic is required". Но такие явные вещи как `static_assert(false)` в каждой специализации GCC, например, отлавливает (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e54156f10b6b4cf7). То есть код не компилируется независимо от того, используется/инстанцируется эта функция или нет.